# Android file descriptor leakage debuging

Tags: java, android, linux-kernel, file-descriptor

I our company we have a lot of ui-tests which are run on virtual/real devices. After running for some time tests randomly crashing, which I think is the result of file descriptor exceeding: I used

`ls /proc/${PID}/fd | wc -l` and `lsof -p ${PID}`
but it did not help  a lot - most of the rows in lsof looks like:

```
30015    u0_a104  678      sock                                    859560 socket:[859560]
30015    u0_a104  679      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventpoll]
30015    u0_a104  680      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventfd]
30015    u0_a104  681      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventfd]
30015    u0_a104  682      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventpoll]
30015    u0_a104  683      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventfd]
30015    u0_a104  684      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventpoll]
30015    u0_a104  685      0000                0,8                 4539 anon_inode:[eventfd]
```

So my question is: is there any android/java/linux instruments/utils to find the **source** of leakage?

**P.S.** System.gc() did not help

Comment: You are leaking files or sockets or Selectors.

Comment: Yes, but what Classes in Java use them? How to find them?

Answer (score 8):

I have researched for this question for a while and would like to share what I found:

1. File descriptor are used in Android at least for:

   - Network sockets (or another type of file)
   - Mapped to memory files
   - Threads - so it was my case. See below why
2. If you have created a HandlerThread, even if the last link to the HandlerThread instance will disappear thread will still work and consume FileDescriptor
3. Threads in android can be seen:

   - In "Java heap dump"  in Memory Abalyze Tool - so I have seen > 500 threads while running intsrumentation tests - they "eat" all file descriptors
   - Via terminal on android device `adb shell ps -t` or just `ps -t`

Comment: Another way to see the threads is via Android Studio's CPU profiler.