# Android trace file descriptors leak in production

Tags: android, sqlite, debugging, android-ndk, adb

Sometimes our users having an app crash due to sudden inaccessibility of database:

```
1) android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file (code 14)
```

or

```
2) java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
```

or

```
3) android.database.CursorWindowAllocationException: Cursor window allocation of 2048 kb failed. # Open Cursors=1 (# cursors opened by this proc=1)
```

And I noticed that in that moment I can't even extract logcat:

```
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301): 2019-07-17_16:57:20.598+0300 [FileUtils] logcat extraction error
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301): java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [logcat, -d, -v, time] Working Directory: null Environment: null
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:174)
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:247)
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:190)
....
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Too many open files
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
07-17 16:57:20.722 E/APP ( 2301):   ... 8 more
```

So I'm getting a question - is it possible to get in runtime (on user's device)
a list of all opened file descriptors in my process
(and pull it to logcat, for example)?

P.S. I failed to run a process to write logcat to file.
But getting a dump app.hprof file working...
Although I haven't found anything special here.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer to the exact question asked, but one that might be able to help you solve the problem: ensure that all of your file descriptors are wrapped in RAII types so you can't forget to close them. In Android we use `unique_fd` for this: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/base/include/android-base/unique_fd.h.

This of course only helps with a subset of leaks. It won't help if the problem actually is that you're using too many file descriptors at a time, but it will help you with the more common case of just forgetting to close a file descriptor.

Comment: I think it's not real file objects leaking, it's may be broadcasts, intents or smth like this...as pointed in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36569771

Comment: thank you for your reply. But we haven't native code in our project. Only one dependency has some native code - implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'

Comment: how do I use unique_fd in NDK project? I can't find this header filer under NDK's directory.

Comment: It's not a part of the NDK. Just copy the file I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can read and dump (I prefer Crashlytics for this kind of reporting) the [list of open file descriptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs#Linux) from `/proc/self/fd`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Alex Cohn's advice I've written some code
that stores

```
/proc/self/fd
```

information in cache

```java
import android.support.v4.util.LruCache;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public class CrashlyticsUtils {
    private static final String TAG = "Crashlytics";
    private static final LruCache<java.util.Date, String> crashlytics = new LruCache<>(20);
    private static final long INTERVAL = 10 * DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS;
    private static long lastTime = 0;

    private static String extractShellCommand(String command) {
        Process process = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

            StringBuilder log=new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            log.append(String.format("Executing a command '%s'", command)).append("\n");
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                log.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            return log.toString();

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "logcat extraction error", e);
            return "";
        }
        finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "logcat reading error", e);
                }
            }
            if (process != null) {
                process.destroy();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addLogNow(String log) {
        Date now = now();
        if (now.getTime() > lastTime + INTERVAL) {
            crashlytics.put(now, log);
        }
    }

    public static void collectSomeLogs() {
        addLogNow( extractShellCommand("ls -l /proc/self/fd") );
        addLogNow( extractShellCommand("lsof") );
        waitSomeTimeout();
    }

    public static void waitSomeTimeout() {
        lastTime = now().getTime();
    }

    public static void printCrashlyticsInfo() {
        Map<Date, String> snapshot = crashlytics.snapshot();
        for (Map.Entry<Date, String> entry : snapshot.entrySet()) {
            Log.d(TAG, String.format("record from %s", entry.getKey()));
            String[] strings = entry.getValue().split("\n");
            for (String line : strings) {
                Log.d(TAG, line);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Date now() {
        return new java.util.Date();
    }
}
```

So I'm written calls among my project

```java
CrashlyticsUtils.collectSomeLogs()
```

and then (when uncaught exception happened) write logs to logcat

```java
CrashlyticsUtils.printCrashlyticsInfo()
```

(you can write in print method anything else that desirable)